# Finding the smallest set of values that make an exponent of a known value.

Tags: calculus, optimization, lambert-w

I need some help with figuring out an equation or process? Not sure what the correct term is?

*Full disclosure: Unfortunately I’m not even remotely a mathematician so I’m grateful for your patience. If I misuse any vocabulary or am unclear please let me know and I’ll try tor clarify what I’m trying to convey.*

## The Question.

The question is simple. I want to figure out the exponent of a value. But there is caveat:

- Only the total is known.
- And out of all the possible exponents that could be used: I want to find the smallest possible base with the smallest possible power.

That is to say: If I was to take the digit of the base number $x$ and the digit of the exponent power $y$, that both these numbers would be as small as possible without making the other larger.

Essentially the resulting pair of numbers would essentially be the smallest difference of values and/ or the smallest sum total.

Moreover I need to “*prove*” that it is the smallest combination of numbers possible. Unfortunately it can’t be “close enough.” It needs to be certain that this pair of numbers are the smallest pair possible values that can form the exponent total.

Here is an example that I hope illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

*(But remember, I’m not just trying to find the answer. Rather I want to know if there is a mathematical process to finding the smallest possible pair in the first place?)*

> Let’s say that the equation is $x^{y} = 64$.
>
> The most simple exponent is $64^{1}$. But it is also the largest number I could use as a base and so would not be considered a “successful” answer, (even if the exponent is only $1$).
>
> $2^{6}$ would be considered more “successful” exponent. As the numbers are $2$ and $6$.
> It doesn’t matter if the base is smaller than the exponent. The only criteria is that they are made of the smallest numbers as viewed as a decimal value.
>
> $4^{3}$ I believe to be the most successful. The base may have significantly increased but we have reduced the exponent by half its value.
>
> $8^{2}$ would be less of a successas it has still gained a higher number. Whilst it is the smallest exponent possible aside from $1$, the base has risen to $8$.
>
> Now, the first question would be how do I find $4^{3}$ out of all the exponents I could possibly use? Then secondly how can I be certain that there is no smaller combination of numbers that could be used to create an exponent that results in $64$?.
>
> Or put another way: Is there a method of mathematically finding the smallest pair of numbers without simply wading through every possible exponent that makes the original sum and comparing the total sum and/or difference of every pair?

Thank you in advance! I know I’m probably over complicating this but unfortunately I don’t know what I don’t know.

> edit: Here is the link @SohamSaha post using positive integers in case anyone should need it: [Minimising $x+y$ in $x^y=a$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838503/minimising-xy-in-xy-a)

Comment: Would it be all right if both the base and exponent are real values instead of integers?

Comment: It seems like you want to minimize $x + y$ such that $x^y = 64$.

Comment: If reals are permitted, then I think $3.153^{3.621}$ is approximately your best bet.

Comment: Real numbers are permitted . But it’s not the smallest value of 64 I’m looking for. Rather I want to know if there’s an equation to finding the smallest value that $x$ and $y$ can be when $x^{y} = a$

Comment: Note that your question falls in [tag:calculus] so [tag:algebra-precalculus] might be somehow off here. You asked a good question, by the way.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I’ll see if I can edit the tags

Comment: Hi. Could you explain why you consider $2^6$ to be better than $4^3$? What are you trying to minimise exactly? Minimise $x+y$? Minimise $x\times y$? Minimise $x^2+y^2$? Minimise $\left| x-y \right|$? Minimise $\max(x, y)$? Maximise $\min(x, y)$? Personally I feel that the most "natural" thing to minimise would be $x^2+y^2$ but that's a somewhat personal feeling.

Comment: Regarding  *"If I misuse any vocabulary or am unclear please let me know and I’ll try tor clarify what I’m trying to convey."*. I don't think you have misused vocabulary, and your example is extremely clear, so it's all good. However the sentences that precede the example are too vague / ambiguous to be able to convey your problem. I think your post would be easier to read if you started with the example, or with a short sentence such as "Given a constant C, I want to solve equation $x^y = C$ while minimising $x$ and $y$." Anyway, it's a very interesting problem, thank you for asking it.

Comment: Since the smallest difference is zero, you could use the solution of $x^x=64$, where x ~= 3.39912154005228

Comment: I have created a separate question linking to this one for the case when $x$ and $y$ are restricted to being positive integers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838503/minimising-xy-in-xy-a)

Comment: @Stef hello! Sorry for the late reply! The reasoning for why $4^{3}$ was more successful was down to the difference between numbers. And I appreciate the advice on the formatting of the question! In future I’ll try to be more concise in my post.

Comment: @SohamSaha Thank you for posting about positive integers! I have read through the comments and am sorry I didn’t get round to posting it myself. (Sleep is a curse). It’s been fascinating to see how people have taken this on and learn all at the same time. I’ve gone and added a link to your post in the main  text so others can find it much more easily.

Comment: @ObliviousGeorge In that case if what you want is to minimise the difference then you should definitely take $y = x$ and not $y = x \ln x$, since obviously $y=x$ gives $|x-y| = 0$.

Comment: Can you write a function in terms of x and y that you want minimized?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are asking to minimize $x + y$ given some fixed constant $a > 0$ such that $x^y = a$. Since we are optimizing in two variables, we solve this using [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). We let $f(x, y) = x + y$ and $g(x, y) = x^y - a$. Then, we need to find a constant $\lambda$ such that $$\begin{align*}\frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial x} &= \lambda \frac{\partial g(x, y)}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f(x, y)}{\partial y} &= \lambda \frac{\partial g(x, y)}{\partial y} \\ g(x,y) &= 0.\end{align*}$$

The operation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ means to take the derivative (or if you want, the rate of change) of $f$ with respect to $x$ while treating all other variables (in this case, $y$) as a constant.

The first two equations become $$\begin{align*}1 &= yx^{y - 1} \\ 1 &= x^y \ln x\end{align*}$$ which, by transitivity, is just $yx^{y - 1} = x^y \ln x$. Dividing both sides by $x^{y - 1}$, we get $y = x \ln x$. Note that we didn't even need to get $\lambda$ here.

Hence, we just need to solve $x^{x \ln x} = a$. Then, $x$ will be the base, and $x \ln x$ will be your exponent.

---

I don't have any idea how to solve $x^{x\ln x} = a$ as I believe it will need to use some techniques involving the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150731/discussion-on-answer-by-soupless-finding-the-smallest-set-of-values-that-make-an); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 12):

**This is not an independent answer and continues the one given by @soupless**

Proceeding with the answer given by @soupless, we can solve their equation like so:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&x^{x\ln x}=a \\
&\Rightarrow&\ln a=x(\ln x)^2=e^{\ln x}(\ln x)^2 \\
&\Rightarrow&\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}=\exp\left({\frac{\ln x}{2}}\right)\frac{\ln x}{2} \\
&\Rightarrow&\frac{\ln x}{2}=W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right) \\
&\Rightarrow&x=\exp\left({2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Also, solving for $y$:
$$y=\frac{\ln(a)}{2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}$$

So, $(x,y)=\left(\exp\left({2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}\right),\frac{\ln(a)}{2W\left(\frac{\sqrt{\ln a}}{2}\right)}\right)$ is the final solution.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the effort put in here. Hopefully I’ll be able to get a clearer understanding of everything once I’ve put both answers together and gone through them slowly so I understand what the process is.

Comment: @ObliviousGeorge, the question was quite good by the way... And best of luck on your journey into the mathematical world.

Comment: @ObliviousGeorge And just as a side note, whenever you see the same variable beside the base and in the exponent, like $xe^x$, try to think of the [LambertW](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)

Comment: Will do, thank you for the link! (Not sure what LambertW is yet but I’ll know soon enough!)

Comment: @ObliviousGeorge You could open a new question (linking to this one) for the integer case, I am very curious about what that might lead to...

Comment: Possibly https://or.stackexchange.com could be a good place to ask for the integer case, if there is no closed-form math solution and we're looking for an integer-programming formulation instead. Also, if you do ask a new question about this, please add a comment here to tell us about it :)

Comment: @Stef thought I'd try on MSE once before going to OR. Here's the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4838503/minimising-xy-in-xy-a)

Comment: Interestingly, or.stackexchange has the question [How to write the $\binom{x}{y}=C$ constraint](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/modeling-the-choose-function) but I couldn't find "How to write the $x^y = C$ constraint".

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a bit unclear to me, but to me, the most reasonable interpretation is the following:

> Given a real number $a>1$, find positive real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x^y=a$ and $x+y$ is minimal.

I'll explain the restrictions to positive $x$ and $y$, and $a>1$, after solving this question.

From $x^y=a$ it follows that $y=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}$. Because $a>1$ and $y>0$, it follows that $\ln a>0$ and so $\ln x>0$, meaning that $x>1$. Now you want to minimize
$$f(x)=x+\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}.$$
Because $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}_{>1}$, the set of reals greater than $1$, we must have $f'(x)=0$ if $f(x)$ is minimal. Some elementary calculus shows that
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{\ln a}{x(\ln x)^2},$$
and so if $f(x)$ is minimal then we must have $x(\ln x)^2=\ln a$. This implies
$$y=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}=\frac{x(\ln x)^2}{\ln x}=x\ln x.$$
It also follows that $\sqrt{\ln a}=\sqrt{x}\ln x$, and so for $w:=\sqrt{x}$ we have
$$\sqrt{\ln a}=w\ln w^2=2w\ln w,$$
meaning that $w\ln w=\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a}$. This equation, in general, does not have a solution in terms of elementary functions. But for every $a>1$ there exists a unique real number $w$ such that $w\ln w=\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a}$, and this real number $w$ is denoted by
$$w:=W(\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a}),$$
where $W$ denotes the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). It follows that the unique minimal pair $(x,y)$ with $x^y=a$ is
$$x=W(\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a})^2,\qquad y=x\ln x=2W(\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a})^2\ln W(\tfrac12\sqrt{\ln a}).$$

---

If we do not require $x$ and $y$ to both be positive, then we still find from $x^y=a$ that $y=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}$, but now we see that as $x$ approaches $1$ from below the value of $y$ goes off to negative infinity. That is to say
$$\lim_{x\uparrow 1}y = \lim_{x\uparrow 1}\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}=-\infty.$$
This is also clearly seen in the graph of $y$, here for $a=64$, as plotted by WolframAlpha:
[image]

This means we can make $x+y$ arbitrarily small, all the way to negative infinity, while keeping $x^y=a$. So there is no minimum of $x+y$, and so it makes sense to require that $x$ and $y$ must be positive.

Similarly, if we allow $a\leq1$, the situation gets messy:

- For $a=1$ we may take $x=1$ and then we can again take $y$
  arbitrarily small, all the way to negative infinity. So again there is no minimum.
- For $0<a<1$  we can have $x$ approach $1$ from above, and as before have $y$ be
  arbitrarily small, all the way to negative infinity. So again, there is no minimum.
- For $a\leq0$ we must certainly have $x\leq0$, but then it becomes unclear what     $x^y$ should even mean if $y$ is not an integer.

This is why I chose to restrict the question to $a>1$ and $x,y>0$.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I do appreciate that the question was worded vaguely. I was trying to express what the smallest pair of numbers could be made from an exponent, and have quickly realised that what often sounds simple is actually often incredibly complicated and currently a bit beyond me. But your solution is very helpful! -Although I must confess yet again maths is something I struggle with so it takes awhile for me to break down explanations.

Comment: You're welcome. So have we interpreted correctly that by 'smallest pair of numbers' you mean the pair of numbers $(x,y)$ for which $x+y$ is minimal?